# What is the unstable space of $0$ with respect to this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 0 \\
        0 & 1/2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$
I was told that the unstable space $W^u(0) = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: \lim_{n \to -\infty} A^n \cdot(x,y) = (0,0) \}$ is the $x$-axis, but I think the unstable sapce is $\mathbb R^2$ \ the $y$-axis because for any points in $\mathbb R^2$ \ the $y$-axis, its $x$ coordinate tends to infinity. Is my answer correct?

Comment: Surely you notice that the formula has $n\to-\infty$.

Comment: Really? $A(x,y)^T=(2x,y/2)^T$. If anything, the $y$-coordinate tends toward zero as you multiply by $A$ more and more.

Comment: @amd Thank you. You are right. I wated to say that the $x$-coordinate tends toward infinity.

Comment: @JohnB So, my answer to the unstable space is correct?

Comment: @amd So, my answer to the unstable space is correct?